# MySQL INSERT query error when values are numbers

Tags: mysql

I am using this code to insert into a database, however for some reason it is giving me an error now. Is there a something that needs to be done when it is numbers?

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'replace, pick) VALUES ('8', '1', '6', '1')' at line 1

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TRIPLECROWNscratch (user_id, original, replace, pick) VALUES (:user_id, :original, :replace, :pick)";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $_POST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':original', $_POST['original'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':replace', $replace, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':pick', $_POST['pick'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO TRIPLECROWNscratch (user_id, original, `replace`, pick) VALUES ...
```

Comment: dang those reserved words haha